# My function to create a lock file causes Access Violation

Tags: c++, file, exception, locking

I have written a function to create a text file in a given directory and write the current processID to it

The function is called when the OK button is clicked on a dialog, it seems to do what I want but when I call it the application crashes when the dialog closes. (If I remove my function it closes without trouble).

This is what I have:

```
void LockFolder(UnicodeString folderLocation)
{
  DWORD processID = GetCurrentProcessId();
  _TCHAR currentProcessID[sizeof(DWORD)];
  _TCHAR* lockID;
  _TCHAR* lock = folderLocation.c_str();
  fstream lockFile;

  _stprintf(currentProcessID,_T("%i"),processID);
  _tcscat(lock,_T("Lock.txt"));

  lockFile.open(lock,ios::out);
  lockFile<<currentProcessID;
  lockFile.close();
}
```

Made some changes but the problem is still there,
Version 2:

```
void LockFolder(UnicodeString folderLocation)
{
  DWORD processID = GetCurrentProcessId();
  _TCHAR* lock = folderLocation.c_str();
  _tcscat(lock,_T("Lock.txt"));

  fstream lockFile;
  lockFile.open(lock,ios::out);
  lockFile<<processID<<"\0";
  lockFile.close();
}
```

Comment: What is `folderLocation`? If it's std::wstring, you can't assing its c_str() result to wchar_t *, as it should be const wchar_t *, and then you can't use it as _tcscat output buffer!

Comment: Neither can you output stream an array of chars that is not null terminated, as it decays to a pointer and is interpreted as a C-string.

Comment: the string is now null terminated, the text file seems to be being written ok but I'm still getting the crash :s

Answer (score 0):

In these lines you corrupt the heap:

```
_TCHAR* lock = folderLocation.c_str(); 
_tcscat(lock,_T("Lock.txt"));
```

Instead, do the following:

```
std::stringstream str; // or wstringstream
str << folderLocation << "Lock.txt"; // or L"Lock.txt"
std::string lock = str.str(); // or wstring
```